# Python equivalents of the common Perl modules?

Tags: python, perl, migration

I need to rewrite some Perl code in python. So I'm looking for the closest modules to what I'm using now in Perl (i.e. with similar functionality and stability):

- [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI) + [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD::mysql)
- [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::UserAgent)
- [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize)
- [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::LibXML)
- [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TreeBuilder)
- [CGI::FormBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::FormBuilder)
- [Template::Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template::Toolkit)

What are the Python equivalents to these?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a short description or link explaining what each of these does. Considering how different the philosophies Perl and Python can be, it's safe to assume that many Pythonistas won't be familiar with the Perl modules.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- All Python database modules use the same API, so either [`MySQLdb`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) or [`oursql`](http://packages.python.org/oursql/) will work.
- [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)
- [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
- [`etree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/)
- No direct equivalent, but [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and `lxml` can parse, and `etree` and `lxml` can generate.
- [`FormEncode`](http://formencode.org/)
- [`Genshi`](http://genshi.edgewall.org/), [`Jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/), `mako`, `cheetah`, and too many others

`urllib2` and `etree` are in the standard library; the rest are easy enough to get.

Answer (score 15):

#### DBI + DBD::mysql

- [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)

#### LWP::UserAgent

- [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) (Python STL)
- [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) (Python STL)

#### WWW::Mechanize

- [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

#### XML::LibXML

- [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html)
- [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/)

#### HTML::TreeBuilder

- [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (Python STL)

#### CGI::FormBuilder

- [cgi](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) and [cgitb](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html) (Python STL)

#### Template::Toolkit

- [Template-Python](http://template-toolkit.org/python/index.html)

**Note:** Items marked above as Python STL are included as part of the Python Standard Library as listed in the [Python v2.6.4 documentation](http://docs.python.org/).